# How with document.write, or something like that, display the table with content when we need?

Tags: javascript, html-table, width, conditional-statements

I need display different content when screen width less than 768px and normal.

I tried something like this, but it don't work:

```
<script>
if(screen.width <= '768') 
{ 
document.write( '<table class="small-tbl"> ... </table>' ); 
} 
else  
{ 
document.write( '<table class="beeg-tbl"> ... </table>' ); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What does *"it don't work"* mean? No table shows up at all? Only one or the  other shows up? I see no reason why what you provided wouldn't work at all.

Comment: aren't css media-query made for this?

Comment: This looks fine as it is.  Although you might want to consider using InnerHTML rather than trying to put it all in an IF statement.

Comment: Don't use document.write. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @user3526229: That comment doesn't make sense. Yes the table shows up, or no it doesn't show up.

Comment: @phylax media-query it is not what I need. the content is quite different

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".cart-tbl-small" ).hide();
     $( ".cart-tbl-beeg" ).hide();
     });
         </script>
             <script>
                var windowSize = $(window).width();
     $(document).ready(function(){
     if(windowSize <= '768') 
{ 
$( ".cart-tbl-small" ).show();
} 
else  
{ 
$( ".cart-tbl-beeg" ).show();
} 
     });
     </script>
```